# Different Datetime format from SQL Server to Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, datetime-format

I have a question, when I extract the dates from SQL Server and send it to Excel, the date formats are different, some come with this format **12-31-2019**, and some others come with this format **12/31/2019**.
Why this can be happening?

My guess is they are built on different SQL Server versions, but I'm not sure.
I will appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: When you say SQL, do you perhaps mean MS SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, it is MS SQL Server

Comment: How do you extract the dates from SQL Server to send them to Excel? Creating a connection from Excel, exporting to a CSV, using SSIS, or another method?

Comment: exporting to CSV

Comment: Are the dates in the SQL server database stored as text, not as 'date'?